# OpenOffice.org: macro help

Tags: macros, openoffice.org, calc

In OOo Calc

I need to copy a column (only **the values**, not the format) from one sheet to another (in the same worksheet) using a macro assigned to a button.

I browsed a bit around but found nothing significant :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the original question:

use a data array, which will be significally faster on large ranges of cells

```
Source = ThisWeek.getCellRangeByName("H12:H206")
source_data = Source.getDataArray()

Target = Steering.getCellRangeByName("M12:AU206").setDataArray(source_data())
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I could build the answer and started learning OOo Basic, which I managed to avoid until now ;-)

I give it as is.

```
Sub UpdateThisWeek

Dim Doc As Object
Dim ThisWeek As Object
Dim Steering As Object
Dim Source As Object
Dim Target As Object
Dim Week as Integer

Doc = ThisComponent
ThisWeek = Doc.Sheets.getByName("This week")
Steering = Doc.Sheets.getByName("Steering")
Week = Steering.getCellByPosition(6,4).Value
Source = ThisWeek.getCellRangeByName("H12:H206")
Target = Steering.getCellRangeByName("M12:AU206").getCellRangeByPosition(Week-19,0,Week-19,194)

Dim i, s
For i = 0 To 194
    s = Source.getCellByPosition(0, i).Value
    If s > 0 Then
        Target.getCellByPosition(0, i).Value = s
    Else
        Target.getCellByPosition(0, i).String = ""
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```