# How to make a macro "atomic"

Tags: macros, openoffice.org, atomic

IOW how do I make OOo's undo/redo work properly when a macro is executed?

This is related to my previous question: [#853176](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853176/openoffice-org-macro-help)

Answer (score 1):

You can talk to the UndoManager, calling `enterUndoContext()` at the very beginning of your macro and then `leaveUndoContext()` at the end. For example:

```
Dim undo As Object
undo = ThisComponent.UndoManager
undo.enterUndoContext("MyAtomicTest")
...
[YOUR COMPLEX OPERATIONS HERE]
...
undo.leaveUndoContext
```

This creates an atomic undo operation that appears to the user as "MyAtomicTest".

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly straight off for me.

Answer (score 1):

for those among us who prefer a JavaScript to write OOo macros, here is a minimal snippet that *should* work (it's tested but I isolated this code from a bigger context):

```
importClass( Packages.com.sun.star.document.XUndoManager );
importClass( Packages.com.sun.star.document.XUndoManagerSupplier );
var doc           = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument();
var undo_manager  = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XUndoManagerSupplier, doc).getUndoManager();
undo_manager.enterUndoContext( 'your descriptive title here' ); 
// get stuff done
undo_manager.leaveUndoContext();
```